# iTerm2 - smart selection for URL's did not work correct

Tags: iterm2

How can I fix the smart selection? Even if you delete all other rules, it doesn't works correctly.
[image: terminal]

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was wrong?

Answer (score 3):

check this setting!

Setting > General > Selection > Double-click performs smart selection